# Inadvertent edge case for achievement 500 rep -> review questions

Tags: support, downvotes, privileges

I recently got 500 reputation pts. Now I can review questions. I decided to look at one. It was a "late answers" review and the answer was bad. I downvoted and left a comment explaining why I downvoted and voilà, I have 499 points and now I'm below the threshold and can't review any other questions.

My concern (and I am biased because I only had the chance to use the feature one time) is that the system does not incentivize me to continue reviewing posts and I'm not sure if that was the point of giving me access in the first place.

Comment: Yeah this happens when you're on the threshold, the good news is it sounds like you're reviewing correctly and when you're not borderline and can safely review without going <500 again, you'll make a fine addition ^^

Comment: Good job! I wish I was like you when reviewing. If the answer was NAA/SPAM/RA, then you may get the 1 reputation back. Plus one upvote means you can downvote like 9 answers.